# TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Intl.RelativeTimeFormat('en', { style: 'short', numeric: "auto" })')

Tags: javascript

I have code like:

```
const rtf = new Intl.RelativeTimeFormat('en', { style: 'short', numeric: "auto" });
```

which in Safari/605.1.15 triggers the error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Intl.RelativeTimeFormat('en', { style: 'short', numeric: "auto" })')
```

How does one in modern JS work around the fact that Intl API might not be present?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This method is not well supported. [Can I use RelativeTimeFormat?](https://caniuse.com/#search=RelativeTimeFormat)

[image]

What you can do is using a package that will emulate the functionnality you need, whatever the browser is.

I've found [relative-time-format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/relative-time-format) npm package you can use.

---

**Install**

> npm install relative-time-format --save

**Use**

```
import RelativeTimeFormat from "relative-time-format"
import en from "relative-time-format/locale/en.json"

RelativeTimeFormat.addLocale(en)

// Returns "2 days ago"
new RelativeTimeFormat("en", {
  style: "long" // "long" is the default. Other options: "short", "narrow".
}).format(-2, "day")
```

---

To check if the browser is compatible or not :

```
if (Intl === void 0 || typeof Intl.RelativeTimeFormat !== 'function') {
   // Browser not compatible
}
```

---

Alternative :

```
const rtf = (Intl &&
            Intl.RelativeTimeFormat &&
            new Intl.RelativeTimeFormat('en', {
               style: 'short',
               numeric: "auto",
            })) || false;

if (!rtf) {
   // Not compatible
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use a package. I just need a way of telling when `rtf` is there or not in browsers that do not support it. Do people do a try..catch ?

Comment: @hendry Ok then. I've added how to check if the function exists or not

Comment: How do I instead set `const rtf` to something that can be used or checked? e.g. `if (rtf) { id.innerHTML = rtf.format(parseInt(seconds / 60), 'minute'); } else { id.innerHTML = parseInt(seconds / 60) + "m"; }`

Comment: @hendry I've added an alternative so you could directly check at `rtf` value